# Eslint - Failed to load parser @babel/eslint

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'm trying to set up Eslint and Prettier for my React Project. For this, I choose the Airbnb Rules Set.
Now I am stuck at the integration of Eslint and Prettier in my VS Code. It already worked but threw me some weird arrows like:

```
Unexpected argument :
```

When defining Types.

I found searched for a solution and hit installing a Parser. So I tried to install @babel/eslint-parser .

But after following [this](https://tjaddison.com/blog/2021/03/updating-babel-eslint-to-babeleslint-parser-for-react-apps/) guide I'm getting the following error.

```
Error: Failed to load parser '@babel/eslint-parser' declared in 'src\.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module '@babel/eslint-parser'
```

As the error implied that @babel/eslint-parser was missing i tried reinstalling with:

```
npm i @babel/eslint-parser @babel/preset-react -D
```

Now I'm left a little bit clueless.

This is my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
    extends: ["airbnb", "prettier"],
    plugins: ["prettier"],
    parser: "@babel/eslint-parser",
    parserOptions: {
      requireConfigFile: false,
      babelOptions: {
        presets: ["@babel/preset-react"]
      }
    },
    rules: {
      "prettier/prettier": ["error"],
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": ["off"],
      "react/prefer-stateless-function": ["off"],
      "import/extensions": ["off"],
      "import/no-unresolved": ["off"],
      "indent": ["error", 2]
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the Solution by myself. For anyone having a similar issue in the Future. Check your npm packages. The different versions of mine were incompatible and that hindered the usage of babel.

Comment: Which packages did you run into with this issue? Having trouble tracking mine down.

Comment: @Matt I found that my issue was the outdated typescript package. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

i had the same issue, the package should be installed properly otherwise it does not work as it should, TO FIX IT DO THIS:

```
npm install babel-eslint --save-dev
```

DONT FORGET TO "NPM RUN BUILD" AFTERWARD